# ColdFusion Reporting Options

Tags: reporting-services, coldfusion, jasper-reports, ireport, microsoft-reporting

We currently use Report Builder with ColdFusion. This Report Builder hasn't seen any Adobe development in around 5 years and doesn't look like it will see any soon.

I need a scalable reporting solution that will work in the cloud without huge licencing implications. I've looked at Crystal (which I don't understand the pricing or what I need) and JasperReports with iReport, and I guess that Microsoft SQL Reporting is an option also.

I'd like to get some recommendations on what people are using and how you have integrated that into ColdFusion. I appreciate that it may not be as seamless as Report Builder.

We are using Windows 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008 in a Cloud infrastructure.

What ever solution we come up with, the resulting output of the reports need to be PDF.

Comment: who designs the reports? developers, power users, end users?

Comment: where I work we developed our own reporting tool. The pre-built options were much too expensive compared to what I knew I could build myself.

Comment: Reports are written by developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used Crystal, SQL Report Builder and ColdFusion Report Builder.

Crystal and SQL Report Builder are much better than ColdFusion Report Builder. Like you said CF is not going anywhere and is really buggy to me.

Crystal is great but it becomes really expensive when you want to publish reports to the web. The standard product requires a report viewer that is installed locally. If you need to publish to the web it is much more expensive.

SQL Report Builder is a really good option. Version 3.0 is really nice and makes it very easy to write advanced SQL queries or call SPs and publish to the web.

I am a pretty big fan of SQL Report Builder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok SQL Report Builder sounds good, I don't understand the licensing or if its included with SQL Server. Also can you point me to how you call and generate a SQL Report from ColdFusion and generate a PDF?

Comment: For anyone still looking: we still have most of our reports in CF Report Builder.  However, due to its limitations there are some things it's not capable of doing.  For these reports we use Prince and just generate the HTML/CSS to send to it.  It's very pricy (so that doesn't meet the OP's licensing stipulation), but if you have the budget and need to do serious reports, it may be worth checking out.